# Slide in from right with opacity:0 jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Pretty simple question; How can I have a opacity:0 element slide into view from the right (similar to slideDown effect)?

Comment: By creating some HTML, CSS3 and eventually not even using JS / jQuery

Comment: animate its opacity (if you want to see it) and its position or tranform.

Comment: Or if you really want to use jQuery, you can add more of it, as in jQuery UI, which lets you define any direction for sliding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest is to assign a **class** with **JS**, and let **CSS** do the job for you.
Using an *Event* like `click` would smell like:

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $(".fadedOutLeft").toggleClass("show");
});
```

```css
/* demo styles */

#wrapper{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#box{
  height: 100px;
  background: #0bf;
}



/* Initial styles */

.fadedOutLeft{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform: translateX(100%);  /* go fully right */
}

/* jQuery added ".show" styles */

.fadedOutLeft.show{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<button>Toggle .show</button>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="fadedOutLeft" id="box"></div>
</div>
```